# GWT tries to load a deleted module

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I am using Eclispe with Google plugin for AppEngine and GWT. Recently I created a test GWT module, but eventually it has been deleted from the project and I can not find any sign of it in the project now.

However, whenever I run the web app locally, I get in console the following message:

```
Loading modules
   com.piq.exemity.Test
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/XXXXXX/Test.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

Has anyone got any idea where it can be hiding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be there in two places -

1. When you invoke GWTC (via the compile option in Eclipse), the module name com.xxx.Test is passed to the compiler. This causes GWT to look for com/xxx/Test.gwt.xml file
2. You could have a module that inherits the module "com.xxx.Test". Check your gwt.xml file if this is the case

I think (1) is more likely the culprit.

Comment: Yup, thanks. Just removed old debug configuration and created it again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the module Test from the Run configuration compiler arguments list. It worked.

Answer (score 18):

Open Run Configurations... from the Run pulldown menu and go to tab Arguments. In the Program arguments box delete the path to your deleted module.

Comment: That fixed my problem.  I had changed the app name and everything else associated with it, except the debug configuration. Thanks!